# Arduino C++ vector of int

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, arduino

I have a class named Model and in ypur .h file I have this:

```
private:
    vector<int> memory(MEMORY_SIZE);
```

MEMORY_SIZE is a const in a define header with value 10.

when I try compile I'm gettind this error code

```
Model.h:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
Model.h:33: error: expected ';' before '<' token
```

I don't know why this, I'm declaring the type of vector...

---

The complete header code:

```
/*
 * Model.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 13, 2012
 *      Author: ademar
 */


#ifndef MODEL_H_
#define MODEL_H_

#include "Config.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <vector>

class Model {

    public:
        Model(int pin, char command[]);
        Model(int pin, int initialState, char command[]);
        bool isChanged(int currentState);
        char* getCommand(void);
        int getState();
        void setRange(int range);
        void usesMemory();

    private:
        int pin;
        int state;
        int range;
        long time;
        char* command;
        void updateTime();
        bool useMemory;
        std::vector<int> memory;
};

#endif /* MODEL_H_ */
```

---

And the C++ code:

```
/*
 * Model.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 13, 2012
 *      Author: ademar
 */

#include "Model.h"

Model::Model(int pin, char command[]) {
    *this = Model(pin,0,command);
}

Model::Model(int pin, int initialState, char command[]) {
    this->pin = pin;
    this->state = initialState;
    this->command = command;
    this->range = 1;
    this->useMemory = false;
    this->updateTime();
}

void Model::usesMemory(){
    this->useMemory = true;
}

void Model::setRange(int range){
    this->range = range;
}

bool Model::isChanged(int currentState) {
    if ((currentState >= (this->state + this->range) || currentState <= (this->state - this->range)) && ((this->time+WAIT_CHANGE)<millis())){
        this->state = currentState;
        updateTime();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

char* Model::getCommand(){
    return this->command;
}

int Model::getState(){
    return this->state;
}

void Model::updateTime(){
    this->time = millis();
}
```

---

And the error:

```
In file included from Honda.h:11,
             from Honda.cpp:8:
Model.h:33: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'vector' with no type
Model.h:33: error: invalid use of '::'
Model.h:33: error: expected ';' before '<' token
```

Comment: <vector> included? std:: added?

Comment: @Kylo I'm included vector, and I already trying with vector<int> and std::vector<int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my shots that *vector* is not included or you are missing namespace `std::`. The compiler explicitly points out that it does not know what vector is.

What is more, you don't initialize fields like this in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29). You have to do it in the constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define MEMORY_SIZE 10

class Clazz {
    std::vector<int> memory;

    public:
        Clazz() : memory(MEMORY_SIZE){}
        int memory_size() {return memory.size();}
};

int main() {
    Clazz c;
    std::cout << c.memory_size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not solve :/, do you make this wth arduino? I go paste all code on question.

Comment: Nope, this is standart c++ and should work everywhere. Apparently it does not for andruino. Here is one of the first things I found in google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986591/vectors-in-arduino

Comment: Really in arduino it don't work, i'm using standarts arrays, thanks. only a detail in arduino i do an array follows: `int memory[MEMORY_SIZE];`.