# User controlled traversal of SD card directory on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, sd-card, fileinfo

I am trying to write a program that allows for uses to traverse the contents of a SD card with buttons on a touch screen (assume there is only one level of files; aka no folders). However, I am finding it impossible to get a "list" of all the files on the SD card:

- I can't just create an array of `strings`or `char*` because I don't know the number
  of files on the card. Besides, I want the container to be dynamic if
  possible.
- I can't create a vector because Arduino doesn't recognize `std::vector`
  or `vector` even when I have [C++](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus) for [Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986591/vectors-in-arduino).
- Searching google produces `new` does not exist in Arduino's C++

I could use `malloc` (or `new`), but that would involve me creating my own container class. As interesting as that may be, the goal of what I am doing is not to implement a dynamic container class.

Have I missed something major in my search for such a function?

Comment: Have you seen this? [List SD directory contents using native library?](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=55851.0).

Comment: @SamRad Yes. Unfortunately, I cannot get that code to work for the SD card Im using. It keeps on failing at `if (!card.init(SPI_HALF_SPEED, chipSelect))`, even though I have gotten the SD card to work with other SD examples

Comment: What error do you get? They suggest to use `if (!card.init(SPI_QUARTER_SPEED, chipSelect))` if it fails. See [SD.begin() returns false](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=140770.5;wap2)

Comment: @SamRad I get false at that line

Comment: Still? Even with Quarter Speed you get false?

Comment: @SamRad Yes. I tried 2 different SD cards

Comment: I wanted to suggest the approach @mpflaga mentioned. I think it's worth trying.

Comment: @SamRad Yeah. Im looking through it right now

Comment: Also [this](http://www.ladyada.net/products/microsd/). Check the `Recursively listing/reading files` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at my example [MP3 File Player](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/FilePlayer/FilePlayer.ino) and the [Web Player](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/WebPlayer/WebPlayer.ino).

There are TWO issues:

1) You need to approach this from the point of view appreciating the Arduino does not have enough resources (SRAM) to hold a list of entire SdFAT's directories. Hence my approach was to use the users console for retaining the list. It dumps the directories contents to the console, along with a corresponding number. From which the user could select the number they wish to enter. Similarly the [Web Player](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/WebPlayer/WebPlayer.ino) does the same thing, but when generating the HTML, it generates a link pointing to the corresponding listed item. Hence the list is stored on the console being either the Browser or Serial Monitor.

2) The default provided SD library is not sufficient to do what you want. Recently Arduino incorporated [Bill Greiman’s SdFatLib](http://code.google.com/p/sdfatlib/) as the under the hood class. But limited it. Where using Bill’s native SdFat library allows you the use of additional methods to access individual objects, such as `getFilename()`, not available in SD. This is necessary when going through the directory. The `sd.ls(LS_DATE | LS_SIZE)` will only dump directly to serial. Where you need to use access the individual files themselves. As show below or [in actual code](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/FilePlayer/FilePlayer.ino#L380)

```
SdFile file;
char filename[13];
sd.chdir("/",true);
uint16_t count = 1;
while (file.openNext(sd.vwd(),O_READ))
{
  file.getFilename(filename);
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.print(F(": "));
  Serial.println(filename);
  count++;
}
file.close();
```

Additionally there are buried public methods accessible by references as show in [WebPlayer’s ListFiles()](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/Examples/WebPlayer/WebPlayer.ino#L110) function, to get more discrete handling of the files.