# Vector Class in Arduino

Tags: vector, arduino

I've written a program in C++ which includes vectors but the file won't compile in Arduino. Is there any library / some way to make sure that vectors work in Arduino.

Plus I can't change it to arrays as the code is quite lengthy and converting it would cause problems.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986591/vectors-in-arduino. Also, http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/ may be helpful.

Comment: I actually followed the first link you mentioned and I'm still getting a problem. Can you please refer to my following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921314/issues-with-standardcplusplus-library-in-arduino

Comment: Do you really need a vector, perhaps an array can do the job ?
For example if you need bisect, splice or some advanced feature or just basics like append, pop.
I you need basic feature, you can quickly write it on pure C.