# Issues with 'StandardCplusplus' Library in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I had to write some code for Arduino in C++. The code works perfectly, but wouldn't work in Arduino as I had used some libraries like vectors, ifstream, etc.

So I included the StandardCplusplus library. I downloaded the [zip version of  the library](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus).

I copied the extracted version into the library folder of Arduino. Now the vector library works, i.e. it doesn't give any compile error.

But on `#include fstream`, Arduino gives the following error: **fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory**

Comment: `unistd.h` is not a C or a C++ header! It is a POSIX header.How did you try to include ?  `#include <sys/unistd.h>`  You can also try Arduino Plus from here  `https://github.com/smeshlink/Arduino-Plus`

Comment: Sorry edited the question. I was using #include<fstream> but that is the error I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but maybe someone else encounters the same problem, just like me looking for an answer couple of minutes ago. I turned the problem from an error to a warning by defining a symbol ARDUINO (I use eclipse, so I added a new symbol in the project's `Properties` --> `C/C++ Build` --> `Settings` --> `AVR Compiler` / `AVR C++ Compiler` --> `Symbols`. Don't know what you're using, but you could add `-DARDUINO` when calling avr-g++). The problem is in ios.cpp file, where you have:

    `#ifdef ARDUINO
    #include <HardwareSerial.h>
    #include <serstream>
    #else
    #include <fstream>
    #endif`

As soon as the ARDUINO symbol is seen in the ios.cpp file, two earlier includes are taken instead of the fstream.