# Converting c++ code into arduino with string and stream header files and functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, arduino, header-files

I'm developing a project on my arduino board, for my projection of the idea I wrote the code in `C++`. But certain library files and functions weren't found on the arduino IDE which are found in `C++` to my knowledge.

I'm attaching the code below.
I want to convert the whole code into arduino in which only the `convertToEnglish` will remain as a function in the arduino .
I tried replacing the header files and others functions with string library and other `Stream.h` header file but almost everything ended up in vain.
Hence to over come this please quote me a solution.
I tried using [Standard c++](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus) as quoted but still the getline fucntion reports an error stating that the cin was not declared in scope.

```
#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include <system_configuration.h>
#include <unwind-cxx.h>
#include <utility.h>



#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

 string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[]);

int main()
{
string input = "";
cout << "Please enter a string in morse code: ";
getline(cin, input);

string const morseCode[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.",
"--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};

cout << convertToEnglish(input, morseCode) << endl;


return 0;
}

 string convertToEnglish(string morse, string const morseCode[])
 {
 string output = "";
 string currentLetter = "";
 istringstream ss(morse);

size_t const characters = 26;

while(ss >> currentLetter)
{
    size_t index = 0;
    while(currentLetter != morseCode[index] && index < characters)
    {
        ++index; //increment here so we don't have to decrement after the loop like if we put in the condition
    }

    output += 'A' + index;
}

return output;
}
```

error message:
Arduino: 1.6.8 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

E:\brain\arduino\sketch_mar15a\Blink\Blink\Blink.ino: In function 'int main()':

Blink:19: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope

```
 getline(cin, input);

         ^
```

exit status 1
'cin' was not declared in this scope

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The string and sstream header files  cannot be found in arduino ide. If not wat are the other header files to use to produce the same output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vectors in Arduino](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986591/vectors-in-arduino)

Comment: You shoud switch the order of the tests of `currentLetter`: before `index < characters` and after `currentLetter != morseCode[index]`. Otherwise you can acces `morseCode[26]`

Answer (score 0):

It' not clear, for me, what you can use and what you can't.

Supposing that you can't use `std::vector`, but you can use good old C string (char *) function and input/output functions, I've prepared the following C-style example

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


char * convertToEnglish (char *                      output,
                         std::size_t                 dimOut,
                         char const * const          input,
                         char const * const * const  morseCode,
                         std::size_t                 numMorseCodes)
 {
   if ( (nullptr == output) || (0U == dimOut) || (nullptr == input)
       || (nullptr == morseCode) || (0U == numMorseCodes) )
      throw std::runtime_error("invalid input in cTE()");

   std::size_t   posOut = 0U;
   std::size_t   index;
   char const *  ptrI0;
   char const *  ptrI1;
   char          currentLetter[5];

   std::memset(output, 0, dimOut);

   for ( ptrI0 = input ; nullptr != ptrI0 ; ptrI0 = ptrI1 )
    {
      ptrI1 = std::strpbrk(ptrI0, " \n");

      if ( nullptr == ptrI1 )
       {
         // last character if the string isn't cr terminated
         if ( sizeof(currentLetter) <= strlen(ptrI0) )
            throw std::runtime_error("to length last char in cTE()");

         std::strcpy(currentLetter, ptrI0);
       }
      else
       {
         if ( sizeof(currentLetter) <= (ptrI1 - ptrI0) )
            throw std::runtime_error("to length char in cTE()");

         std::memset(currentLetter, 0, sizeof(currentLetter));
         std::strncpy(currentLetter, ptrI0, (ptrI1 - ptrI0));

         if ( '\n' == *ptrI1 )
             ptrI1 = nullptr;
         else 
            ++ptrI1;
       }

      for ( index = 0U
           ;    (index < numMorseCodes)
             && strcmp(currentLetter, morseCode[index])
           ; ++index )
       ; 

      if ( numMorseCodes <= index )
         throw std::runtime_error("no morse code in cTE()");

      output[posOut] = 'A' + index;

      if ( ++posOut >= dimOut )
         throw std::runtime_error("small out buffer in cTE()");
    }

   return output;
 }


int main ()
 {
   constexpr char const * morseCode[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.",
      "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..",
      "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-",
      "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};

   constexpr std::size_t  numMorseCodes
      = sizeof(morseCode)/sizeof(morseCode[0]);

   char *       input = nullptr;
   std::size_t  dim   = 0U;

   if ( getline(&input, &dim, stdin) == -1 )
      throw std::runtime_error("error reading input");

   char  output[1024];

   std::cout << convertToEnglish(output, sizeof(output), input,
                                 morseCode, numMorseCodes) << std::endl;

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

If you can use `std::vector` or `std::string`, can be made really simpler.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English